# SQL Server log file grew 40GB with Hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have developed an Hangfire application using MVC running in IIS, and it is working absolutely fine, till I saw the size of my SQL Server log file, which grew whopping 40 GB overnight!!

As per information from our DBA, there was an long running transaction, with the following SQL statement (*I have 2 hangfire queues in place*)-

```
(@queues1 nvarchar(4000),@queues2 nvarchar(4000),@timeout float)
delete top (1) from [HangFire].JobQueue with (readpast, updlock, rowlock)
output DELETED.Id, DELETED.JobId, DELETED.Queue
where (FetchedAt is null or FetchedAt < DATEADD(second, @timeout, GETUTCDATE()))
and Queue in (@queues1,@queues2)
```

On exploring the Hangfire library, I found that it is used for dequeuing the jobs, and doing a very simple task that should not take any significant time.
I couldn't found anything that would have caused this error. transactions are used correctly with `using` statements and object are `Disposed` in event of exception.

As suggested in some posts, I have checked the recovery mode of my database and verified that it is simple.

I have manually killed the hanged transaction to reclaim the log file space, but it come up again after few hours. I am observing it continuously.

What could be the reason for such behavior? and how it can be prevented?

The issue seems to be intermittent, and it could be of extremely high risk to be deployed on production :(

Comment: Did you set a custom value for the `SqlServerStorageOptions.QueuePollInterval` property? What value is used?

Comment: @odinserj: No I haven't changed it. It should be using default 15 second interval.

Comment: How many workers do you have in total?

Comment: @odinserj - I have 20 workers in total

Comment: @odinserj - Please correct me if I am wrong, I observed that the transaction remains open till the job is executing. So for a long running job which takes some hours to get completed, the transaction is open and it keep increasing the log size. If that's correct, how it can be fixed.

Comment: @odinserj: Just 1 question, having separate DBs did solved the issue, but I still didn't got, what was causing the issue. Why the logs were being maintained for the CRUD operations for transaction which is not opened by HF, and what difference a separate DB made that it stopped writing those logs? Can you please update your answer with this? It would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Long-running transaction prevents transaction log truncation in both Simple and Full Recovery modes. All the transactions, implicit or explicit, are written to the log file without any removal (long-running transaction blocks this) for both your application and Hangfire itself. You can read more in [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29830).

Comment: Can you please help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422631/net-framework-to-manage-background-running-processess-on-seperate-machines/48448965#48448965

Comment: @Learning-Overthinker-Confused - I have tried to answer your post, hope that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from Hangfire 1.5.0, `Hangfire.SqlServer` implementation wraps the whole processing of a background job with a transaction. Previous implementation used *invisibility timeout* to provide *at least once* processing guarantee without requiring a transaction, in case of an unexpected process shutdown.

I've implemented a new model for queue processing, because there were a lot of confusion for new users, especially ones who just installed Hangfire and played with it under a debugging session. There were a lot of questions like *"Why my job is still under processing state?"*. I've considered there may be problems with transaction log growth, but I didn't know this may happen even with Simple Recovery Model (please see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29830) to learn why).

It looks like there should be a switch, what queue model to use, *based on transactions* (by default) or *based on invisibility timeout*. But this feature will be available in 1.6 only and I don't know any ETAs yet.

Currently, you can use [Hangfire.SqlServer.MSMQ](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server-with-msmq.html) or any other non-RDBMS queue implementations (please see the [Extensions](http://hangfire.io/extensions.html) page). Separate database for Hangfire may also help, especially if your application changes a lot of data.

Comment: +1 for your answer @odinserj. Now I know what is official about hangfire. I will work more on the issue, and will try to find out the solution. One thing that come to my mind is that the application and hangfire DBs are same right now. Probably that's causing the issue. I will try testing again with separating the databases. And your tool is awesome :)

Comment: Consider using MSMQ extension, this will remove long-running transactions completely, and the latency will be minimal due to blocking calls while fetching a job. Background job information will stay in SQL Server, but queues will be driven by MSMQ in this case.

Comment: Having a separate DB for hangfire solved the issue to an extent of no worries. Its very smooth now. Having said that, it is best to go with msmq or redis etc. storage for best performance.